# Software not downloading after new MacBook pro reboot

Tags: macos, catalina, startup

My uncle just got me a brand new MacBook pro 13 inch from the US. Upon receiving it he had already made a user name without attaching an apple id with it. He used it just to see if it's working fine. However upon receiving it I wanted a clean slate so I decided to reboot it (it is only 5 days fresh and has no data).

Upon following online instructions on rebooting I decided to clear my drives first then reinstall macOS Catalina from the boot menu. After a couple of hours of downloading time. The laptop resets and shows me the error that 'security settings do not allow this mac to use an external startup disk'. I haven't even used an external startup disk' for rebooting. If tried 3 times restarting deleting the memory then downloading the macOS again but it keeps giving me the same error. Please help as it is a brand new Mac and I'm scared I've ruined or deleted it's OS already. (PS it's my first mac?)